# Const.EXTRA_DATA error

Tags: android, android-intent

I am new in SO, and also new in Android. I try to make some chat application and I want to use this code

```
ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listUser);
list.setAdapter(new UserAdapter());
list.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
  {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
      startActivity(new Intent(UserList.this, Chat.class).putExtra(Const.EXTRA_DATA, uList.get(pos).getUsername()));
    }
  });
```

But the problem, there is error for `Const.EXTRA_DATA` because it can not be resolved and also `uList.get(pos)` too, I use Android Studio. I got that code from video tutorial.

Comment: did you defined EXTRA_DATA in Const ?

Comment: For the second part, try changing `uList` to just `list`

Comment: I think Const is a class from Android? @VividVervet

Comment: nope,  android does not have such class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the comments you understood that Const is a predefined class, unfortunately it is not, there is no such class available in android library.
so your code will be like

```
startActivity(new Intent(UserList.this, Chat.class).putExtra("EXTRA_DATA_KEY", uList.get(pos).getUsername()));
```

since the key has to be used in both activities (sending activities and receiving activity) usually defines in a separate Java file.

Comment: Owh ok, Vivid Gratias tibi valde

Answer (score 0):

Hello dear you are using your **code snippet like**

```
Const.EXTRA_DATA
```

right?

--> as you told us you are new SO please check your are having

`class` **named**
**`Const`** and

having static string variable like

**`EXTRA_DATA`**

-> SO finaly your class will appear like

```
public class Const{

public static String EXTRA_DATA="EXTRA_DATA";

}
```

Comment: Owhm, thank you, mate. But is Const a default class from Java? or Android maybe?

Comment: nop it just using for defining string if you didn't get from your code example put your own it would not affect its just a key name only trust me :)

Comment: @MikeS if it helped you so you could vote me up for your help :)